# loading and displaying contents of json file into markdown

Tags: json, markdown, readme

I have a json file (random_file.json):

```
{
    "some_stuff": {
        "some key": "some value",
        "other key': "other value"
    },
    "other_stuff": {
        "some key2": "some value2",
        "other key2': "other value2"
    }
}
```

I would like to display this in my readme.md markdown file. Currently I'm just copying and pasting.

````
```json
{
    "some_stuff": {
        "some key": "some value",
        "other key': "other value"
    },
    "other stuff": {
        "some key2": "some value2",
        "other key2': "other value2"
    }
}
```
````

This works fine for now, but is a little messy and requires future json changes to be re-copied and pasted. Is there a way to load and display json data from within the same repo?

Ideally I could display different parts of the json file:

````
my_json = load("my_repo/random_file.json")
```json
my_json["other_stuff"]
```
````

as the equivalent of:

````
```json
"other stuff": {
    "some key2": "some value2",
    "other key2': "other value2"
}
```
````

Comment: I don't think external resource loading is part of any markdown *standard*, so what converter are you using? It seems markdown is not your output format, but only something that gets then converted to something a user is intended to see?